# Using mod_rewrite got some File does not exist messages in Apache logs

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

My `mod_rewrite` rules are working fine but sometimes similar errors showing up in my error logs:

`File does not exist: /var/www/examplesite/exampleurl`

Of course the requested directory doesn't exists, page properly served but my error logs growing.

What can cause these errors?

Comment: Can we assume this is from the Aache ErrorLog?

Comment: @Joshua Hoblitt Yes, this is from Apache's error logs. mod_rewrite is working fine (e.g. when i open examplesite.com/exampleurl, i got the correct page as a result).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start by changing the loglevel for your rewrite engine:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel

> Example
>
> RewriteLogLevel 3

This should help diagnose if there is an issue with the rewrite rules or perhaps some other parameters for the client requests(perhaps they have incorrect Host parameters, etc).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've modified my conf but nothing changed, all i got is `File does not exist: /var/www/examplesite/exampleurl`